# Mule : No receiver found on secondary lookup of receiver on connector: HTTP_HTTPS with URI key: https://myhost:443/robots.txt

Tags: mule, robots.txt

I have these warnings filling all my logs. It seems to be caused by crawlers and spiders http://www.robotstxt.org/

```
No receiver found on secondary lookup of receiver on connector: HTTP_HTTPS with URI key: https://myhost:443/robots.txt.
org.mule.transport.http.HttpsConnector: Receivers on connector are: {
```

I cannot find anyone who had this issue on the web before me...
I want to get rid of it in my flow, how can I do that? I can share the code but I don't see how it is relevant in this case.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you using the new HTTP connector or the old HTTP transport?

Comment: the old in this case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you're having can be reproduced through the following steps:

Add an inbound endpoint that has the following url: http://localhost:8081/test, start your app and call http://localhost:8081/something.txt

The explanation is: There is no inbound endpoint that matches the beginning of the url you're calling, the easiest solution is to have a catch-all flow with an inbound endpoint whose address is http://localhost:8081/ and log (or not) every message received in that flow.

Comment: Hey Juan thanks for the response, I thought there would be a less "gross" way to remedy this issue, but it seems like the only solution. Based on your idea I created a flow with no path and just add a set payload that says "hello robot" just for the hell of it. I don't log any of it and don't get the problem!

Answer (score 1):

This [MuleSoft tutorial](https://developer.mulesoft.com/docs/display/current/Basic+Studio+Tutorial#BasicStudioTutorial-EditingtheApplication) explains how to filter our requests for `favicon.ico`. You should be able to do the same with requests for `robots.txt`

New HTTP Listener in 3.6+:

```
<expression-filter
    expression="#[message.inboundProperties.'http.request.uri' != '/robots.txt']" />
```

For 3.5.0 and less:

```
<expression-filter
    expression="#[payload != '/robots.txt']" />
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, should have stated that I had tried that. But it didn't work.

Comment: Oh. Still getting the error in the question with the filter in place or the filter breaks your config?

Comment: Yes the warning message / log still doesn't get filtered, but it doesn't break my config. I've added it to every flow to be sure but it doesn't change anything.